# Why do I use gradient descent for a linear regression instead of differentiating for the minimum error point?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, gradient-descent

I am wondering why we use gradient descent instead of just differentiating to find the minimum error point. From my limited mathematical knowledge, the total error is a quadratic form and we can just differentiate the minimum error point.

Comment: You can and should differentiate and solve. Lots of people don't because they are confused. If you solve the resulting linear system iteratively with conjugate gradient, you will solve the problem faster with less work guaranteed. Or you can solve the resulting linear system with a direct method, which may be better or worse depending on the structure of the matrix